# How to make my input text field only allow letters properly?

Tags: angular

I'm validating the entry of text only in my field

in my login.component.ts

```
letterOnly(event) : Boolean{
    const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if ((charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

and in the login.component.html

```
 <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Usuario" formControlName="userName" (keypress)="letterOnly($event)">
```

It works on Windows but on the Mac keyboard, it doesn't.

[**Solution** for me]

only replace the regexValidator

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: "[OnlyNumber]"
})
export class OnlyNumber {
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private ngControl: NgControl) {}

@Input() OnlyNumber: boolean;

@HostListener("input", ["$event"])
@HostListener("past", ["$event"])
onInput(event) {
  const filteredValue = this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(
    /[yourRegex]/g,
    ""
  );
  this.ngControl.control.setValue(filteredValue);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change check charCode by

```
function letterOnly(event) 
{
            var charCode = event.keyCode;

            if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || charCode == 8)

                return true;
            else
                return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use pattern validator:

```
<input type="text" matInput placeholder="Usuario" formControlName="userName" ngModel pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*">
```

Second option:

You can keep your "letterOnly" method but instead comparing ASCII, use regex.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working since the ascii-table is different between Mac and Windows.

[Windows Table](https://ascii.cl/)

[Mac Table](http://ascii-table.com/ascii-extended-mac-list.php)

In your case, use [Angular Pattern validation](https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator).

Example:

```
<input name="firstName" ngModel pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*">
```